# Linux(Ubuntu 20.04) - Installed New SSDs, Trying to resize old filesystem to use the newly added storage

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, raid

Completely fresh to linux, have been trying to research a way around this issue with no dice, wondering if anyone can assist with the below.

I have rented an Ubuntu 20.04 distro server and have RAID1 on the mounted filesystem (/dev/md2). This filesystem has now run out of space.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.5M   13G   1% /run
/dev/md2        1.6T  1.6T  4.1G 100% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        9.8G  153M  9.2G   2% /boot
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
```

So I ordered 2 new SSDs 3.8TB each.

They show up like so,

```
├─nvme2n1p1   128G linux_raid_member part  
│ └─md0     127.9G swap              raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme2n1p2    10G linux_raid_member part  
│ └─md1        10G ext3              raid1 /boot
└─nvme2n1p3   1.6T linux_raid_member part  
  └─md2       1.6T ext4              raid1 /
nvme1n1       3.5T                   disk  
nvme3n1       3.5T                   disk  
nvme0n1       1.8T                   disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   128G linux_raid_member part  
│ └─md0     127.9G swap              raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2    10G linux_raid_member part  
│ └─md1        10G ext3              raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3   1.6T linux_raid_member part  
  └─md2       1.6T ext4              raid1 /
```

Now, I can see that they are disks, probably means not partitioned, and unused. I am trying to get the md2 filesystem to extend and make use of the new 3.8 TB storage that has recently been added. How exactly do I go about extending the md2 filesystem to make use of the new 3.8TB disks I recently ordered?

Thank you in advance!